# Not clear on using to_categorical from keras.utils

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

My labels are like

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I have 10 classes. So for this

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I should get *1*. But my output is coming like

```
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

I am very new to this, can you please explain me why is this happening and what's the right way to do it.

Comment: You probably don't need to convert to categorical, your already have your target in categorical format

Comment: How do I convert my labels into integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is already in one-hot encoded format.
 to_categorical converts label encoded data to one-hot encoded format:

Example:

```
y = [2,4,5]
num_classes = 10
keras.utils.to_categorical([y],10)
#output
#array([[[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

given input, y=1 and num_classes=10, it will give output [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

From your question it seems that you want to canvert one-hot ([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) encoded to original class label encoded format.
For that you can use *np.argmax()* as below:

```
import numpy as np
one_hot_y = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
label_encoded_y = np.argmax(y)
#It will give label_encoded_y = 1

#one more example
one_hot_y = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
label_encoded_y = np.argmax(one_hot_y,axis=-1)
#it gives label_encoded_y as array([2, 4, 5])
```